# React App Cannot find module '@/client/context/RepContext' , Failed to compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I have existing React Web application. i have run

```
npm i 
and npm start
```

when i run the application in browser. i am getting this error
[image]

Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install `@/client/context/RepContext`

```
npm install @/client/context/RepContext
```

now run again.

Comment: npm ERR! Could not install from "@/client/context/RepContext" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: getting above error

Comment: I checked npm for this package but it does not exist! It might sound stupid but try commenting it out.

Comment: so this is not solution for me

Comment: Is it possible that this is some custom package? try searching ```@/client/context``` your project folder.